# pass multiple argument to sys.stdout.write

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout

Is it possible to pass multiple argument to `sys.stdout.write`? All examples I saw uses one parameter.

The following statements are incorrect.

```
sys.stdout.write("\r%d of %d" % read num_lines)
Syntax Error: sys.stdout.write

sys.stdout.write("\r%d of %d" % read, num_lines)
not enough arguments for format string

sys.stdout.write("\r%d of %d" % read, %num_lines)
Syntax Error: sys.stdout.write

sys.stdout.write("\r%d of %d" % read, num_lines)
not enough arguments for format string
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to put your variables in a tuple :

```
>>> read=1
>>> num_lines=5
>>> sys.stdout.write("\r%d of %d" % (read,num_lines))
1 of 5>>>
```

Or use `str.format()` method:

```
>>> sys.stdout.write("\r{} of {}".format(read,num_lines))
1 of 5
```

If your arguments are within an iterable you can use unpacking operation to pass them to string's `format()` attribute.

```
In [18]: vars = [1, 2, 3]
In [19]: sys.stdout.write("{}-{}-{}".format(*vars))
1-2-3
```